# Can't resize QFrame

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to hide a QFrame from the start of the app to later on showing it as a warning message with a function.
But I can't find a solution. The frame keeps showing up without changing its start size.
I would also be happy with a solution in Qt Designer but I can't figure out how to do it either way.
`self.frame_top_warning.setFixedHeight(0)` seems to work but makes problems later on when animating that frame.

```
class SampleApp(ui_main.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleApp, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        # Here I want to set the start size to 0 to, later on, animate it in.
        self.frame_top_warning.resize(self.frame_top_warning.width(), 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply hide the `QFrame` with `self.frame_top_warning.hide()`?  Is it not OK?  An alternative could be to set the maximum height of the widget to 0 with `self.frame_top_warning.setMaximumHeight(0)`.  Hope this helps =)

Comment: @WilliamSpinelli I can't use `self.frame_top_warning.hide()`as later when I want to show that window it won't appear or animate in `self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_top_warning, b"minimumHeight")
        self.animation.setDuration(600)
        self.animation.setStartValue(height)
        self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to set the maximum height of the widget to 0 with `self.frame_top_warning.setMaximumHeight(0)` at the beginning to hide the `QFrame`.  Then you can use `QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup` to animate two properties at the same time `minimumHeight` and `maximumHeight`.  In this way you are constraining the height of the widget to be what you want it to be.

I have put together a small example to show you what I mean

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        show_warning_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Warning')
        layout.addWidget(show_warning_button)
        show_warning_button.clicked.connect(self.showWarningLabel)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button'))
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('This is some text'))

        self.frame_top_warning = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame_top_warning.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background: red;}')
        self.frame_top_warning.setMaximumHeight(0)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame_top_warning)

        min_height_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_top_warning, b"minimumHeight")
        min_height_animation.setDuration(600)
        min_height_animation.setStartValue(0)
        min_height_animation.setEndValue(400)

        max_height_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_top_warning, b"maximumHeight")
        max_height_animation.setDuration(600)
        max_height_animation.setStartValue(0)
        max_height_animation.setEndValue(400)

        self.animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.animation.addAnimation(min_height_animation)
        self.animation.addAnimation(max_height_animation)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.show()

    def showWarningLabel(self):
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps =)